# robot_localization: sensor frame in differential mode

Tags: navigation, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to fuse the output of a VIO package (odometry msgs) and GPS. I have been reading the source code of `robot_localization` and noticed that when using the `differential` mode, the resulting velocity is expressed in the `base_link_frame` ([line](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/47b608256f08a0df5a1dd038c94fd5d071e16c72/src/ros_filter.cpp#L2858)). The output of my VIO package is expressed in cam frame (I mean that the odometry messages corresponds to the pose of the camera during the navigation). Is there any way to fuse this output using `differential` mode? To implement this feature in `robot_localization`, would it be enough to rotate the resulting velocity or am I missing something? I'm not sure what the rotation would be anyway.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384179/robot_localization:-sensor-frame-in-differential-mode/) by [jcremona](https://answers.ros.org/users/80632/jcremona/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-08-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe your question is answered [a few lines above](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/47b608256f08a0df5a1dd038c94fd5d071e16c72/src/ros_filter.cpp#L2828). We compute the delta between the two poses (in this case, in the camera frame), then rotate that using the rotation between the sensor frame and the world frame. That should put the delta into your `base_link_frame`.

However, this might not actually help you, especially if you have your camera's transform defined relative to your `base_link_frame` (and you probably do). `r_l` is not good at handling differential poses for sensors whose transforms are defined relative to the `base_link_frame`.

You have two options, I think:

1. Modify the VIO package so that it outputs pose and velocity, and then fuse the velocity directly.
2. As long as you are *only* going to use the sensor in `differential` mode, I *think* you could get away with defining the transform for the camera relative to your `world_frame`, rather than your `base_link_frame`. So if you create a static transform publisher and make it publish a rotation-only transform from your `world_frame` to your `camera_frame` (the contents of said transform should be the rotation of the camera VO data relative to your robot `base_link_frame`). The one downside I can see for doing this is that you won't be able to counter the effects of false linear velocity resulting from turning in place, assuming the sensor is not placed at centre of rotation.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2021-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jcremona](https://answers.ros.org/users/80632/jcremona/) on 2022-02-01**:
Thanks for your reply, Tom. I had thought of using `differential` mode because I couldn't see any other way to correctly fuse a VIO (ORB-SLAM3) with GPS. But in general, what would be the correct way to fuse VIO and GPS? (when the output of the VIO is expressed in a frame other than `base_link` (e.g. in the camera frame))

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2022-02-11**:
Any time you are fusing pose data from a sensor that is affixed to the robot and not at the robot's centroid, you need to handle that offset from the origin before you can fuse the pose data. But in this particular instance the offset *in the world frame* is changing. If the robot is facing 0 degrees, the sensor offset in the world frame might be along the X axis. If the robot is facing +90 degrees, then the offset in the world frame might be along the Y axis. Contrast this with the GPS, for which the measurements just need a fixed transform to be transformed into your world frame.

One option is to write a node that does a *live* computation of the base_link->VIO transform based on the robot's world-frame pose.